# metrics from compilation with the make command

Tags: cmake, makefile, gnu-make, metrics

I use CMake to generate some makefiles that will compile multiple targets using G++ on Linux.
I would like to create some metrics about the compilation such as :

- Time needed to build each target
- G++ warnings and errors

The only solution I came up with so far is to redirect the output of make and parse the whole file but this seems really heavy. I cannot use the G++ flag `-fdiagnostics-format=json` feature since I cannot upgrade to GCC-9.

Any suggestions? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

As far as timing is concerned, consider using [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org) instead of Make. When you build it produces a file called `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/.ninja_log` that can be converted to a format compatible with Chrome's `about:tracing` flame graph format.

There's a script for doing that here: https://github.com/nico/ninjatracing

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for, thank you !! I'll try this out right away and keep you posted. :)

Comment: I've managed to generate the json from the ninja_logs file but I apparently cannot use ninja either because the compilation order is not supported by CMake according to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55225997/manipulate-build-order-for-independent-targets-in-ninja-cmake, but thank you for your suggestion it's much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Something you could do is set the compiler to be a program or shell script that wraps the G++ functionality and add some (similar to how some ccache integrations work):

```
# Makefile
CC := g++-with-metrics.sh
```

```
# g++-with-metric.sh

# 1. Start timer

# 2. Run command, save output (to variable or tmpfile)

# 3. Stop timer, log result

# 4. Parse output for warnings and errors, log result
```

Comment: Oh I did not think of that and it's probably better than parsing the whole make output, thank you! :)